# AADSTS500202: User account from external identity provider 'live.com' is not supported for API version '2.0'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

I followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online) to implment OAuth flow with the following authority url

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=d8e21783-5956-4bef-80ae-fdd636006223&prompt=login&response_type=code&response_mode=query&redirect_uri=xxxxx&scope=offline_access+user.read+files.readwrite.all&state=xxxxx
```

The page provides two sign-in ways:

1. With email address.
2. Without entering the email address.

You can see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It9sx.png), green line is the first option and orange line is the second.
Both of the two login ways supports 「Windows Hello Face」 and 「Security Key」 (Passwordless)

However, the authorization will [fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myl7N.png) if I choose the second sign-in way.

```
AADSTS500202: User account from external identity provider 'live.com' is not supported for API version '2.0'.
```

Does this mean Microsoft OAuth flow not supporting the second sign-in way?

> PS: The ancient authority URL ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)) supports the second sign-in
> way.
>
> ```
> GET https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}
> &response_type=token&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
> ```

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT Hi!, thank you for answering my problem, but the provided information doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online) approach is no longer recommended.

> Use your personal Microsoft account to get access to Azure and all
> consumer-oriented Microsoft products and cloud services, such as
> Outlook (Hotmail), Messenger, OneDrive, MSN, Xbox LIVE, or Microsoft
> 365. [Sign up your organization - Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/sign-up-organization)

***Note:*** Usually  approach  using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint is recommended. However, some enterprise scenarios may require using the original Azure AD endpoint.

Please check this  [Microsoft Docs on Error AADSTS50020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist)  to check for relatable cause to troubleshoot.

**References**:

1. [Get OneDrive data in UWP using Microsoft (Live) Accounts and Azure
   AD - DEV Community](https://dev.to/425show/get-onedrive-data-in-uwp-using-microsoft-live-accounts-and-azure-ad-1jko)
2. [Authorization and sign-in for OneDrive in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)

You can raise a [***support request***](https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/supportRequest/appId).